# SQL Group by doesn't show all variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am getting a list from MSSQL database . I have a system list and materials in a database table. I want to get a summary from a date range. But database is giving me only rows which are not null. Here is my code

```
select system_no AS 'SYSTEM NAME', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN (mat_2='AS') THEN mat_2_size END) as 'AS',
       SUM(CASE WHEN (mat_2='SS') THEN mat_2_size END) as 'SS',
       SUM(CASE WHEN (mat_2='CS') THEN mat_2_size END) as 'CS'
from fabrication_table 
where welding_date between '2014-02-03' and '2014-02-09' 
group by system_no 
UNION 
select 'TOTAL' as 'SYSTEM NAME',
       SUM(CASE WHEN (mat_2='AS') THEN mat_2_size END) as 'AS',
       SUM(CASE WHEN (mat_2='SS') THEN mat_2_size END) as 'SS',
       SUM(CASE WHEN (mat_2='CS') THEN mat_2_size END) as 'CS' 
from fabrication_table 
where welding_date between '2014-02-03' and '2014-02-09'
```

This query's result is below

```
SYSTEM NAME              AS      SS     CS
Auxiliary steam          NULL    NULL   6.75
Chemical dosing          NULL    10.00  NULL
Closed cooling water     NULL    1.50   193.75
Condensate               NULL    NULL   32.00
Demineralized water      NULL    34.00  NULL
Feedwater                NULL    NULL   6.00
Gases (N2, H2, CO2)      NULL    NULL   385.25
GT air intake anti-icing NULL    NULL   220.50
Main steam & by-pass     49.50   NULL   84.00
Seawater intake          NULL    27.50  NULL
ST drains                37.50   NULL   175.50
ST seals steam           NULL    2.25   175.00
TOTAL                    87.00   75.25  1278.75
```

But my System name list is :

```
Potable water
Service water
Seawater intake
Chemical dosing
Closed cooling water
GT interconnections
Feedwater
HRSG blowdown
Sampling
Fire fighting
GT Lube Oil
Auxiliary steam
Desalted water
Demineralized water
ST lube & seal oil
Main steam & by-pass
ST drains
GT air intake anti-icing
Condenser vacuum
ST seals steam
Condensate
Plant drainage
Filtered water
Compressed air
GT drainage
Fuel gas
Gases (N2, H2, CO2)
```

Here is my question: I want to list all of variables e.g. The query doesn't list Fire Fighting but I want to list Fire fighting like this

```
Fire Fighting       NULL     NULL    NULL
```

Comment: i) check "Fire Fighting" manually in table and verify with your where condition of each select.
ii)remove union and use union all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code block

```
SELECT ISNULL(column,0) FROM...
```

It can help me to show null variables

Comment: This answer is incomplete when compared to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Nulls are cut off from aggregates by default.

try to avoid "nulling" values using coalesce:

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN (mat_2='AS') THEN mat_2_size END) as 'AS'
```

changes to:

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN (mat_2='AS') THEN coalesce(mat_2_size,0) END) as 'AS'
```

Comment: 1) Did you put that coalesce for all your [mat_2_size] occurrences or just for that I put on the example above? 2) There are at least one (null or not) row for that specific [system_no] in that date range?

Comment: btw, that union is just to add a summarized total for the result set. I usually let that to be done at the UI layer for the sake of simplicity of the query and DB performance.